# C Segmentation fault: memory altered between functions strcmp

Tags: c, function, recursion, struct, cs50

If anyone could tell me why I can't access the memory at dir.paths[dir.npaths] after populate() returns dir, and how to fix it. That would be much appreciated.

This is a simplification of the problem, it's condensed with all of core elements. I just need to know how to make the comparison work without getting a segmentation fault.

The compare is actually used in an if statement. Eg. if (strcmp(dir..., "file") == 0)

Seek, in the full program, calls populate and becomes a recursive call. Meaning I can't just move the strcmp into the populate function. They need to stay separate.

// Test starts at function populate

// strcmp in seek() function causes segmentation fault

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    string name;
     string type;
}
path;

typedef struct
{
    int npaths;
    path* paths;
}
directory;
```

// Prototypes

```
int seek(directory dir);


int main(void)
{
     directory dir;
     seek(dir);
}
```

// Actual test is below this line

```
directory populate(directory dir)
{
    path newPath = {.name = "file/", .type = "directory"};
    dir.paths[dir.npaths] = newPath;
    return dir;
}

int seek(directory dir)
{
    populate(dir);
    printf("Should return 0\n");

    // Supposedly accesses memory it shouldn't
    printf("%i\n", strcmp(dir.paths[dir.npaths].type, "directory"));
    return 0;
}
```

// If you are cool enough to want to wade through the actual code, thanks.

// Here's a link to pastebin. https://pastebin.com/j8y652GD

Comment: I don't see where `dir.paths` gets initialized to point to any allocated memory.

Comment: What is `string` defined as?

Comment: it's essentially no different from char*, it's someone else library. <cs50.h>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> dir.paths[dir.npaths] = newPath;

Silly question, but do you allocate memory for `dir.paths[]` somewhere? If not, you have to call `dir.paths = calloc (count, sizeof(path))` or `malloc (count * sizeof(path))` with the same effect.

Like @code_farmer noted, you pass data contained in `dir` to `populate` by value and the data gets copied to stack. Of course, nobody takes care of copying on-stack data back. And nobody should. You have to call `populate` like suggested by @code_farmer. And I would even advise you to use pointers when passing structures as arguments to reduce memory footprint and make you life easier in situations like this one.

hth

Comment: Yes, in the full populate function realloc is called and makes room. I was just too stupid to add that into the question. And do you mean call calloc just before I call populate, or inside populate?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. On which system have you tried this code? Theres another potential problem with it. On GNU/Linux you can't always rely on `struct dirent`'s `d_type`. Unless you're on btrfs, ext2, ext3, and ext4 (`man 3 readdir`) you should call `[l]stat` on the file of interest. It may be that you simply don't get the list populated at all because of "defunct" `d_type` field. You should run your program under debugger and check everything carefully.

Comment: Some other notes, in your code at line 160, `printf("%i\n", strncmp(dir.paths[dir.npaths].type, "file", 4));` will cause segfault. Use index `dir.npaths - 1` instead. Don't forget, that base index for C array is 0, not 1. Initilize `directory changing_name;` at line 209 with path you're going to scan. In general, I'd suggest you to think really carefully and to rewrite your code while keeping in mind mentioned here considerations, because there are many issues at hand.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
dir = populate(dir);
```

perhaps can solve your problem.

If you set a breakpoint in line  `populate(dir)`,you will see the dir stay the same after excute this line.

Beccause the paramater of your funtion **populate** is of type **struct**,what passed into **populate** is exactly a copy of dir.

Comment: But populate is supposed to return dir once it's finished modifying dir.npaths.